# n98-magerun: Do we need to drop the old database before importing the new one?

Tags: database, magerun

Do I always have to drop all tables in the old database before importing a new one, or can I just import the new one and it will automatically just update the old database with the new infos?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've to drop the old database to import new database.

> Usually if the same records found in the sense it will skip and import the new datas only as far as my knowledge.

Hope this help.